# Why is my sticky piston not extending?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In a 1.15.2 java server, I want to use this design for a timed bubble elevator, but the sticky piston is not extending. Everything powers up as it should, except the piston.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In theory there could be a bridge of slime connecting the slime blocks to the ground hidden behind the soulsand etc. Of course then you wouldn't ask in this case, but sometimes more perspectives are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your piston is not receiving direct redstone power: Notice how the redstone wire is pointed away from the piston. In order to power that piston, you'll need to either power a block directly adjacent to the piston, or loop your wire around slightly so that it points directly at the piston.

One thing you can do is bring that wire up 1 block: place a block next to the repeater with a piece of redstone on it, and another block directly behind the piston. This should give your piston direct power, allowing this design to work.

Comment: screenshot tk, give me a minute